# Performance issue with query on Axapta database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, axapta

I wrote a query on our Axapta database and rewrote it a hundred times, but the issue remains. It performs very bad. After 15 minutes there is still no results while almost bringing the server down.

Any idea on how to improve this statement is most welcome.

```
SELECT
  J.INVOICEID,
  T.AMOUNTCUR,
  T.RECID,
  T.ACCOUNTNUM,
  CASE WHEN O.DATAAREAID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END hasOpenTrans,
  CASE WHEN P.DATAAREAID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END hasPayment
FROM
  CUSTINVOICEJOUR J
  LEFT JOIN CUSTTRANS T ON
    T.DATAAREAID = J.DATAAREAID AND
    T.INVOICE = J.INVOICEID AND
    T.ACCOUNTNUM = J.INVOICEACCOUNT AND
    T.TRANSDATE = J.INVOICEDATE
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      DATAAREAID,
      REFRECID,
      ACCOUNTNUM
    FROM
      CUSTTRANSOPEN
    GROUP BY
      DATAAREAID,
      REFRECID,
      ACCOUNTNUM
    HAVING
      COUNT(*) > 0) O ON
        O.DATAAREAID = T.DATAAREAID AND
        O.REFRECID = T.RECID AND
        O.ACCOUNTNUM = T.ACCOUNTNUM
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      S.DATAAREAID,
      S.TRANSCOMPANY,
      S.TRANSRECID,
      S.ACCOUNTNUM
    FROM CUSTSETTLEMENT S 
      INNER JOIN CUSTTRANS C ON 
        C.DATAAREAID = S.DATAAREAID AND 
        C.RECID = S.OFFSETRECID AND 
        C.TRANSTYPE IN (0, 8, 15) AND 
        S.CANBEREVERSED = 1
    GROUP BY
      S.DATAAREAID,
      S.TRANSRECID,
      S.TRANSCOMPANY,
      S.ACCOUNTNUM
    HAVING
      SUM(S.SETTLEAMOUNTCUR) > 0) P ON
        P.DATAAREAID = T.DATAAREAID AND
        P.TRANSRECID = T.RECID AND
        P.ACCOUNTNUM = T.ACCOUNTNUM AND
        P.TRANSCOMPANY = T.DATAAREAID
WHERE
  J.DATAAREAID = '011' AND
  J.INVOICEDATE >= '2014-06-01'
```

Since it might matter: here are the existing indexes on the table involved:

```
CUSTINVOICEJOUR
Index Name               Columns                                                        Clustered   Primary Key   Unique
I_062INVOICEACCOUNTIDX   DATAAREAID, INVOICEACCOUNT, INVOICEDATE                        False       False         False
I_062INVOICENUMIDX       DATAAREAID, INVOICEID, INVOICEDATE, NUMBERSEQUENCEGROUP, RECID True        False         True
I_062ORDERACCOUNTIDX     DATAAREAID, ORDERACCOUNT, INVOICEDATE                          False       False         False
I_062PARMIDX             DATAAREAID, PARMID                                             False       False         False
I_062RECID               DATAAREAID, RECID                                              False       True          True
I_062SALESIDDATEIDX      DATAAREAID, SALESID, REFNUM, INVOICEDATE                       False       False         False
I_062VATNUMIDX           DATAAREAID, VATNUM                                             False       False         False

CUSTTRANS
Index Name               Columns                                    Clustered   Primary Key   Unique
I_078ACCOUNTDATEIDX      DATAAREAID, ACCOUNTNUM, TRANSDATE          True        False         False
I_078BILLOFEXCHANGEIDX   DATAAREAID, BILLOFEXCHANGEID               False       False         False
I_078INVACCOUNTDATEIDX   DATAAREAID, INVOICE, ACCOUNTNUM, TRANSDATE False       False         False
I_078INVOICEACCOUNTIDX   DATAAREAID, INVOICE, ACCOUNTNUM            False       False         False
I_078PAYMIDDATEIDX       DATAAREAID, PAYMID, TRANSDATE              False       False         False
I_078RECID               DATAAREAID, RECID                          False       True          True
I_078VOUCHERDATEIDX      DATAAREAID, VOUCHER, TRANSDATE             False       False         False

CUSTTRANSOPEN
Index Name            Columns                           Clustered   Primary Key   Unique
I_865ACCOUNTDATEIDX   DATAAREAID, ACCOUNTNUM, TRANSDATE True        False         False
I_865RECID            DATAAREAID, RECID                 False       True          True
I_865REFRECIDX        DATAAREAID, REFRECID              False       False         False

CUSTSETTLEMENT
Index Name                       Columns                                                               Clustered   Primary Key   Unique
I_075OFFSETCOMPANYRECTRANSREC7   DATAAREAID, OFFSETCOMPANY, OFFSETRECID, TRANSRECID, SETTLEMENTGROUP   False       False         False
I_075OFFSETVOUCHERIDX            DATAAREAID, OFFSETTRANSVOUCHER                                        False       False         False
I_075RECID                       DATAAREAID, RECID                                                     False       True          True
I_075SETTLEMENTGROUPIDX          DATAAREAID, SETTLEMENTGROUP                                           False       False         False
I_075TRANSINDEX                  DATAAREAID, TRANSRECID, TRANSDATE                                     True        False         False
```

Also the size of the tables might matter, or at least gives an idea of the number of records I'm dealing with:

```
CUSTINVOICEJOUR
DATAAREAID       Nbr
011          1513668
012                2
ash           355735
bar           268795
euk           692242
hlm           866154
lil           136163
prv             3180

CUSTTRANS
DATAAREAID       Nbr
011          2383870
012                4
ash           428161
bar           367620
bol               45
euk           630029
hlm          1377005
lil           167405
prv             4148

CUSTTRANSOPEN
DATAAREAID    Nbr
011          6119
012             4
ash          5845
bar          1876
bol            29
euk          8077
hlm          2426
lil          2173
prv           190

CUSTSETTLEMENT
DATAAREAID       Nbr
011          2469546
ash           462982
bar           415329
bol               18
euk           684421
hlm          1419857
lil           178551
prv             4325
```

Comment: Could you show the execution path? It's pretty hard to try and guess what indexes are being used just from seeing the scripts. We could take guesses, but seeing an execution plan would hopefully make it easier to see what happens.

Comment: Axapta appears to be a very SHOUTY database.

Comment: You should be doing this query inside of AX...much easier and doesn't skip business changes.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the execution plan, or the [selectivity](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/selectivity-in-sql-databases/) of the data of the individual columns, and taking into account the query and indexes you posted, it might be worthwhile trying to create covering indexes on the tables.

A quick glance at the query leads me to the following index for the tables involved (basically using every column involved in a `WHERE` clause, or `JOIN`:

```
CUSTINVOICEJOUR - DATAAREAID, INVOICEID, NVOICEACCOUNT, INVOICEDATE, RECID, ACCOUNTNUM
CUSTTRANS - DATAAREAID, INVOICE, ACCOUNTNUM, TRANSDATE, RECID
CUSTTRANSOPEN - DATAAREAID, REFRECID, ACCOUNTNUM
CUSTSETTLEMENT - DATAAREAID, RECID, TRANSTYPE, CANBEREVERSED, TRANSRECID, ACCOUNTNUM, TRANSCOMPANY
```

Keep in mind the above order of the columns is based on the order in which I spotted them in the query. To figure out the ideal order, determine the selectivity per column, and order them in the order based on that, from high selectivity to low.

Try and record the selectivity path before adding a new index, then add the index and check the execution path again to see whether or not the new index is being used (they should be. If they aren't it might indicate a column is missing). When then moving onto the next index, also keep an eye on the indexes you might have just added, just to see if the index you just added might impact the execution path from a moment ago (It shouldn't happen if you caught all the columns used, but this type of behavior could never be ruled out 100%).

Another good thing to keep an eye on is the statistics returned by the server. When adding new indexes, the goal should be to lower the amount of physical reads (disk-based search), and convert them to logical reads (from memory, which is cheaper).

Your mileage might vary, but the above get you off on a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing is misconfigured or some other process is locking a table?
I executed your query on a local db and it executed in about 1 second.

Have a look at your running processes on the SQL server and search for locks.
And you could make use of the query analyser which is part of the SSMS.

Execution plan from this place:
[image]